# Implemented virtual method call fails when called through base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, embedded

I have a class structure like this:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int a1() = 0;
    int a2() {
        return a3();
    }
protected:
    int a3() {
        return a1();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual int a1() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b_obj;
    int value1 = b_obj.a2(); // This fails.
}
```

I am building for a Renesas RX63N processor using the KPIT GNU RX toolchain (a GCC port). As commented, I have tested `B::a2()` and this fails - stepping through with the debugger I generally get an "undefined instruction" exception at some point during the call.

I've reduced the methods down to their barest bones above, retested and I still get the same failure. I'm therefore guessing there's something wrong with the virtual table but I can't figure out what. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: Why doesn't A::a2() return something?

Comment: you have some extra things, so this is not a real example to demonstrate the problem

Comment: A::a2 does not return anything and s_buffer for B::a1 is not defined

Comment: Guys, I've reworked the question - hopefully this better explains my problem. And what's with the downvoting, jeez.

Comment: have you tried this code, and does it fail as described? I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it fails. I'm wondering whether this is a compiler issue?

Comment: And you're not writing `A::a1()` rather than `a1()`? The first would stop the dynamic dispatch and then you'd end up calling an unimplemented function.

Comment: Nope, definitely just `a1()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ideone.com/mIbNbs works. `b_obj.a2()` is correct.

So it should be a bug with your compiler. (or the code you show is not the right one)

Comment: Oooh, cool website. Yeah, a compiler bug is what I was fearing.